# Cut time series when drawdown crosses a given number

Tags: time-series

I want to cut the time series when the drawdown crosses a number. For example, as the drawdown cuts 4%, I want the original time series to cut by 50%, and when the drawdown becomes 2%, the time series reverts from 50% to 100%.

So far, I have the code to generate a random time series and the code to calculate the drawdown. I would appreciate it if anyone knew how to adjust the time series based on the drawdown. Thank you so much for your insights!

```
import numpy as np
import math
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1234)

sigma = 0.07
N = 3
IR = 1
daily_sigma = sigma / math.sqrt(252)
daily_mu = daily_sigma * IR / math.sqrt(252)
days = pd.bdate_range(pd.Timestamp(2022, 1, 1), pd.Timestamp(2022, 12, 31))
T = len(days)

def do_drawdown(cum_pnl_max, cum_pnl):
    return np.maximum(cum_pnl_max.add(-cum_pnl), 0)

def get_daily_gross(target_ir):
    return pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(loc=daily_mu * target_ir, scale=daily_sigma, size=(N, T)), 
                        columns=pd.Series(days, name='date'), index=pd.Series(np.arange(N), name='obs'))

    
daily_net = get_daily_gross(1)
drawdown = do_drawdown(daily_net.cumsum(axis=1).cummax(axis=1), daily_net.cumsum(axis=1))
```